# Missing chars and bad printing

Tags: c

This is my code

```
FILE *fp;
char line[255];
fp = fopen("./games/Dead Space.txt", "r");
// Check if fopen succeeds and those things goes here.

fgets(line, 255, fp);
char name[255];

strcpy(name, strtok(line, "\n"));
printf("%s: a game\n", name);
```

Code explanation: I'm trying to get the first line of `./games/Dead Space.txt` and remove the `\n` **if there are any**.

This is `./games/Dead Space.txt`

```
Dead Space
Shooter, 3D
Electronic Arts
```

And this is the output

```
: a gamece
```

Expected output

```
Dead Space: a game
```

Can anybody help me? Why is this happening?

Comment: Unrelated: remove trailing `'\n'` from `data` with `data[strcspn(data, "\n")] = 0;`

Comment: You probably copied the data file from Windows, or a website where it was posted from WIndows, or conceivably created with a Unixy edtior that supports 'DOS' or 'CRLF' mode like vim, and as a result it contains **CR LF line endings**. You delete the LF but leave the CR, so you then output e.g. `Dead Space<CR>: a game` which displays on your terminal as `: a gamece`. Check with the `file` utility, `cat -v`, `sed -n l` (ell), or similar.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yes, im on windows... How can i fix this?

Comment: What implementation (compiler and library etc) are you using? An implementation _designed_ for Windows like MSVC++ should already translate CRLF to C-style NL, although some don't do so by default: you may need to specify `t` (for text i.e. non-binary) in the `fopen` mode string. If you are using something ported to Windows like cygwin or WSL this is less consistent, although check the documentation; you _may_ need to remove or supporess the CR yourself.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I am using gcc with WSL. I tried using "rt" mode but nothing changes. Can you post your comments as an answer? Thanks!!

Comment: This one comes for free: Check if fopen succeeds.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Haha yes! I skipped that in the question, but I did implement it in my code.

Comment: Add `printf("line=<%s>\n", line);` after `fgets` and tell us what is displayed. Inspect the content of `line` with your favorite debugger.

Comment: WSL is a port, so I wouldn't expect it (presumably its glibc rather than gcc itself) to support the `t` mode. I  _think_ I've heard it does have some kind of Windows/Unix file mapping but I don't know about it; you need someone that does, or (as I said) accept the implementation doesn't do it and do it yourself.